# Nginx, reverse proxy : how to redirect https to http?

Tags: nginx, redirect, reverse-proxy

Beginner in nginx, I have to understand how to configure a reverse proxy for redirecting https requests to http :
Actually, my nginx is configured to redirect https request to differents servers (in my conf. file, I use locations to distinguish url) and it works pretty good.
Now I have to add another internal server which only supports http requests.
I tried by using this kind of block :

> location /OPR {
>
> ```
>             proxy_pass http://$internalfqdn;
>
>             proxy_redirect http://$internalfqdn https://$RP_Public_fqdn;
> ```
>
> }

But I have 2 issues : 
_even if I can reach the login page from outside using https://"FQDN_public"/OPR, I can see in the browser console that it tries to connect some objects (images, scripts...)  using http and the server's internal ip address

_by entering credentials, I reach the page: https://"FQDN public":80/OPR/PasswordSettings.aspx which leads to timeout error (as nginx listens only on 443, it seems normal)

Anyone can help me ? I'm looking to proxy_set options actually, trying to find a solution (the internal server can not be configured to use https ;) )

Edit: I made some configuration and I resolved the use of internal IP address by adding some proxy_set_header.
Now my blocks seems like:

> ```
>  location /OPR {
>                 proxy_pass http://$internalfqdn;
>                 proxy_redirect http://$internalfqdn https://$RP_Public_fqdn;
>                 proxy_set_header Host $host; 
>                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; 
>                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  }
> ```